# Trim Text From String PHP

Tags: php, html, trim

I want remove unnecessary text from my string variable. I have variable like `$from` which contains value like `123456@blog.com`. I want only `123456` from it. I have checked some example for trim but does not getting proper idea for do it. Let me know if someone can help me for do it. Thanks

Comment: It's not trimming, you need to extract all before @ character. try to use 'split' command. And for info - trimming is removing starting and trailnling spaces from string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use explode() for splitting the string.

```
Syntax:
explode('separator', string);

 $result= explode("@", '123456@blog.com');
    print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123456
    [1] => blog.com
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string on the `@` symbol like so:

```
$str = "123456@blog.com";

// here you split your string into pieces before and after @
$pieces = explode("@",$str); 

// here you echo your first piece
echo $pieces['0'];
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/FTALm)